# How to get current user by wso2 bpmn?

Tags: wso2, bpmn, wso2-business-process

How can I get current user when claims task by wso2 bpmn?

I want to get it to call other REST-API

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After claiming the task, he becomes the assignee of that task. You can GET the task info from the rest endpoint https://Host_Name:PORT/bpmn/runtime/tasks/{task-id} and it contains the username of the assignee.

Comment: Yup bro. I know. But i tried to check How to know a user, who has task (like candidate groups) but task is still not claims. I want use REST API

Comment: Then you can use identiyLinks.  GET runtime/tasks/{taskId}/identitylinks GET runtime/tasks/{taskId}/identitylinks/users, GET runtime/tasks/{taskId}/identitylinks/groups. These requests return responses like {
  "userId" : null,
  "groupId" : "sales",
  "type" : "candidate",
  "url" : "http://localhost:8081/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks/100/identitylinks/groups/sales/candidate"
}